# Domain of characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Hey if $X$ is random variable, then what is the domain of characteristic function of $X$? In many books there is written that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, but sometimes authors takes value of characteristic function at point $-i$ (which is complex number) when they caculate $\mathbb{E}(e^X)$. So what is the domain and if complex, what are the differences between these two domains?

Comment: I have never seen any prestigious text book treating the domain of a characteristic function not to be $\mathbb{R}$. By definition, $\phi_X(t) = E(e^{itX})$. Please list the reference in detail for the example you mentioned, if it exists.

Comment: See Section 3 [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1952/2-4/pjm-v2-n4-p08-s.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my comment, the "approach" you mentioned in your post is invalid for some very common characteristic function.

It is well known that the c.f. of the standard exponential distribution $f(x) = e^{-x}, x > 0$ is

\begin{align*}
\phi(t) = \frac{1}{1 - it}, t \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}

When you literally plugging $t = -i$, the denominator will be $0$, hence inconclusive. In fact, the expectation of $e^X$ is not a finite number for this case.

Comment: For example for Variance Gamma process the characteristic function of $X_1$ is of the form $\phi\left(u\right)=\left(1-iu\theta\nu+\frac{\sigma^{2}\nu u^{2}}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\nu}}$ and I calculate $\mathbb{E}(e^X)$ by taking $\phi\left(-i\right)=\phi\left(u\right)=\left(1-\theta\nu-\frac{\sigma^{2}\nu}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\nu}}$. Is this OK or I can't take value of characteristic function at imaginary point? I wonder why, since the domain is real, many authors count the expected value in this way, especcialy in the case of Levy processes

Comment: @Kemi Could you name a specific author, including the publication who does so?